# How to allow swiping over UIButtons to scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a carousel menu of UIButtons in my app. Everything works great except that the buttons are kinda big and it won't scroll when a finger is dragged across the button. The dragging has to be done outside of the button that's currently front and center in the carousel. Is there some setting I can change so that I can swipe across the buttons to scroll and have them also be interactable?

Here's the code that creates the buttons:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500.0f, 320.0f);
button.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
button.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;

button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
button.layer.shadowRadius = 12;
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(12.0f, 12.0f);

[button setImage:(UIImage*)[buttons objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: when the finger drag the button, the button is the first responder, so the button action is triggered. if you want to skip the button action, you may better implement your own touchMoved, touchBegan, touchEnd code

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `UIScrollView` property `canCancelContentTouches` is set to `YES`.

```
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
```

Moreover, a `UIScrollView` implements a  method `touchesShouldCancelInContentView`.

> The default returned value is YES if view is not a UIControl object;
>   otherwise, it returns NO.

This means that `UIScrollView` does not attempt to cancel touches in `UIButtons` which prevents scrolling. Additionally, you can subclass  `UIScrollView` and override `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` to return `YES` when content view object is a `UIButton`.

Comment: I'm not actually using a UIScrollView. Sorry for the confusion. I'm using the iCarousel class found here: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel to create the carousel effect.